# Hide/show multiple WTForm labels

Tags: jquery, html, class, wtforms

How can I hide/show multiple wtform labels. Currently I am doing this.

HTML:

```
 {{ render_field(var_1, class = "class_1") }}
 {{ render_field(var_2, class = "class_1") }}
 {{ render_field(var_3, class = "class_1") }}
```

JQuery:

```
    $('label[for="var_1"]').show();
    $('label[for="var_2"]').show();
    $('label[for="var_3"]').show();
```

Is there a better way? For example assigning a class to the labels?

Thank You!

Comment: That doesn't look like HTML to me.  But do they all have class `class_1`?  You could just target that.

Comment: That only provides a class to the input box and not the label itself. Thanks though

Comment: So logically you could take whatever the class passed in is, and put class +'Label' on the label and target it.  But as I eluded to, instead of posting code that creates code, show us the generated markup that your script is operating against.

Comment: sorry, Im not sure what you mean by generated markup

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show or hide a field for some specific reason, you have to do two things.
First show the fields that you want and hide the fields that you don't want. It could be done using jquery and css.

```
$("any id or class").click(function(){
$('#parent_div_of_field_id_that_you_want_to_show').css('display','block');
$('#parent_div_of_field_id_that_you_want_to_show').attr('data-parsley-required','false') //if you are using parsley for client side validation
$('#parent_div_of_field_id_that_you_want_to_hide').css('display','none');
$('#parent_div_of_field_id_that_you_want_to_hide').attr('data-parsley-required','true') //if you are using parsley for client side validation
```

Now you have to handle the server side validation. You have to stop the validation of those hidden fields. To do this use StopValidation for wtforms.

```
from wtforms.validators import StopValidation
def functionName(form, field):
    if form.your_field_name.data==None:
        field.errors[:] = []
        raise StopValidation()
```

And this function like this

```
name=StringField("Name",  [functionName, validators.DataRequired("Name is required")])
```